# How to read several files from folders and change the column name in r

Tags: r, directory, readfile

I have several folders under one directory and each folder has a txt file with the same name as the folder. For example, the main directory is XYZ, under that, I have 400 folders like A01B, A22C, A12D... Z45F, inside those folders the files are like A01B.txt, A22C.txt, A12D.txt... Z45F.txt. Also, all of those txt files has 2 columns (same length for all the txt files 6000 rows), the first column being same for all the txt files. Now, what I want is to read all of those files into a single data frame with the second column named as the file name, and the first column as ID.

`read.table(XYZ/A01B/A01B.txt)`
will give a table like

```
AA00001    1.5
AA00002    2.3
AA00003    0.5
AA00004    4.8
```

`read.table(XYZ/A22C/A22C.txt)`
will give a table like

```
AA00001    8.6
AA00002    6.1
AA00003    9.5
AA00004    1.1
```

I want a table like this

```
ID         A01B  A22C
AA00001    1.5   8.6
AA00002    2.3   6.1
AA00003    0.5   9.5
AA00004    4.8   1.1
```

Can you please help me with the R code for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so I'm pretty sure there's a more optimized way to do this, but I'm blanking.  If I were going to just crank this out though, I'd do something like this:

```
#tidyverse has all the things I want and more
library(tidyverse)

#this lists all the files in your directory so you don't have to hand jam them
files_list <- list.files(path = "XYZ",recursive = T,full.names = T)

#here, I make a custom function that reads the table and assigns it new column names
read_custom <- function(directory) {
  df <- read.table(directory)
  colnames(df) <- c("ID",str_extract(directory,"\\w+(?=\\.txt"))
  return(df)
}

#do the first one and make a new dataframe
df1 <- read_custom(files_list[1])

#start a progress bar (trust me you want to do these on loops that might take a while)
p <- progress_estimated(length(files_list) - 1)

for(i in 2:length(files_list)) {
  #use our fancy custom reading function to make a temporary data frame
  temp <- read_custom(files_list[i])

  #join it to the old one
  df1 <-  full_join(df1,temp)
  
  #tick the progress bar and print it (seriously, this is so helpful to keep you from going crazy)
  p$tick()$print()
}
```